# i3 automatically start the same application in different workspaces

Tags: window-manager, i3

I would like to start `lxterminal` in both workspace 1 and workspace 2.

The end of `~/.config/i3/config` file looks like this:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec /usr/bin/lxterminal'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 2; exec /usr/bin/lxterminal'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 3; exec /usr/bin/firefox'
```

Resulting in opening 2 instances of `lxterminal` in workspace 1

Comment: You can use i3's `assign` to make sure a window with some specific attributes always ends up on a specific workspace. I use this to make terminals appear on specific workspaces using `assign [instance="term1"] → 1` and launch my terminal (st) with `-c term1` to have that particular instance show up on workspace 1. However, I don't know if you can assign an instance name like this with lxterminal. Maybe look into its profile features and how it affects X properties (use `xprop` to find these), or consider using another terminal if that's an option.

Comment: I had a similar problem at some point, and solved it simply by gathering the `i3-msg` commands, i.e. `i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec /usr/bin/lxterminal; workspace 2; exec /usr/bin/lxterminal`. I think this way of writing the commands will force i3 to execute them sequentially. Not sure this is actually the explanation or that it will work for you...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos Could you please write it more precisely? I tried it exactly as you written it and it doesn't work.

Comment: I see that I forgot the final quote, but I guess that's not the error you encounter?

Comment: @Rastapopoulos I haven't forgot the final quote.

Comment: Hmm I tried it on my browwser, and it works, so I don't know what the problem could be, sorry...